# How to search a PHP PDO AllResults Array

Tags: php, arrays, filter, pdo

I can't figure out how to efficiently get SQL data for a Room/Rates/Dates=Amount...

First I load all the "RateData" for a date range with a PDO select.  There are many rows, for many rooms, each with many rates...  maybe, or maybe it is all empty except a couple of Amounts.  It needs to display $0 for missing dates, so next...

I load the Rooms with PDO and loop through them, and for each room I load the Rates with PDO and loop through them (not a ton of rates per room, and not a ton of rooms, but possibly a very long date-range).

So then I loop through the date range and add $0 to the giant UI grid of Amounts by Rate/Date, nested under each Room.  I have to do this anyway, as I also have a ton of logic on what to display in the parent Room row that averages the Rates and such.

So what I need to do is instead of using $0, I need to see if the Room/Rate/Date exists in RateData...

```
$RateAmount = 0;
$RateDataRow = $RateData.filter('Room=1 && Rate=1 && Date=2022-10-01');
If ($RateDataRow exists) {$RateAmount = $RateDataRow['Amount']}
```

How to I write the above sudocode in PHP?
The only alternative I can think of would be to do 1000's of SQL calls to populate the grid... which seems bad.  Maybe it is not that bad though if PDO caches and doesn't actually query the DB for each grid cell.  Please advise.  Thanks.

I tried this:

```
            $currcost = 0;
            //if $ratedata exists for currdate + currrate + currroom            
            function ratematch($row)
             {if (($row['RoomType_Code']=$currrate) 
               && ($row['RatePlan_Code']=$currroom) 
               && ($row[    'Rate_Date']=$currdate->format("Y-m-d")))
               {return 1;}
              else {return 0;}
             }
            $match = array_filter($ratedata, 'ratematch');
            if (!empty($match)) {$currcost = $match['Rate_Amount'];}
```

But got an error about redeclaring a function.  I have to redeclare it because it is in a loop of currdate under a loop of currrate under a loop of currroom (about 1000 cells).

Comment: tl;dr, have you considered using `where` clause on the sql query? how are your tables looked like?

Comment: You can set us up a ready-to-use [mcve] with realistic data @ https://phpize.online/

Comment: If I use WHERE clause, then that means I have to do 1000 DB lookups.  Bad form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, I just have to manually loop through the RateData...

```
            //Get Amount from DB
            $currcost = 0;
            foreach($ratedata as $datarow)
             {if (($datarow['RoomType_Code']==$currroom) 
               && ($datarow['RatePlan_Code']==$currrate) 
               && ($datarow[    'Rate_Date']==$currdate->format("Y-m-d")))
               {$currcost = $datarow['Rate_Amount'];
                break;
               }
             }
```

If anyone knows a more efficient way to "query" a previous query without a trip to the SQL server, please post about it.  Looping through the fetchAll 1000's times seems bad, but not as bad as doing 1000's of WHERE queries on the SQL Server.

I suppose I could make a 3-dimentional array of $0, then just loop through the RateData once to update that array, and finally loop through the 3-dimentional array to do my other calculations (average rate per room per week sat-sun).  Sounds hard though.

Comment: From an outsider's point of view, it feels silly to ask PHP to filter SQL data -- that's what a WHERE clause is for.  Because we don't understand your challenge, we can't really give you solid advice.  The ball is in your court.  You can take the time to set up a [mcve], or you can opt out of getting professional insights from fellow professional developers.

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clear.  I needed to filter the SQL data so that I only had to get SQL data once instead of 1000+ trips to the SQL server.  Because I never found a way, I instead looped though all (most) of the SQL data 1000+ times (aborting the loop when I found the match) for 1000+ different matches, to populate a grid.

Comment: I provided 3 easy lines of pseudo code and asked if that could be written in PHP...  that pseudo code IS your minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Again... You can set us up a ready-to-use [mcve] with realistic data @ phpize.online  I may re-engage with your question when you clarify your task in a way that proves a WHERE clause is a bad idea.

Comment: Again...  I am in a loop, populating a grid with 1000's of cells with $0 if there is no match, or the SQL data if there is a match.  It should be obvious that using a WHERE clause and hitting the SQL server with 1000's of requests is a horrible idea.